# You uploaded an APK file whose manifest (AndroidManifest.xml) contains several entries with the tag. There should only be one

Tags: xamarin.android

i triying upload my .apk file and im getting this error:

You uploaded an APK file whose manifest (AndroidManifest.xml) contains several entries with the tag. There should only be one.

I have a project who bind a jar file generated from android studio. If i delete the dll who include in android xamarin project, i can upload correctly the apk file. But if i try to upload the .apk with the dll of the .jar bindig project, it fails with the mentioned error

Any idea?

Sorry for bad english, thanks!

Comment: It seems you  have multiple `<application ../>` tags within your manifest, please share your `AndroidManifest.xml` code.

Answer (score 0):

Check your AndroidManifest.xml that is generated in your `obj/Release/android` folder. Inspect it for items that have duplicate tags. You most likely have two `<application>` tags present when there can only be one. You will  have to figure out what is generating the second `<application>` tag if you didn't place it in there manually. (Most likely an issue with manifest merging)